# Sharepoint 2010 Changing Width of List Column

Tags: sharepoint-designer

So I am using an Issue List (the premade template) on SP2010 and two of the columns I have activated for the default view are 'Created By' and 'Modified By', in addition to the 4 or so other columns.  My organization uses very long Display Names in Active Directory so the names in these two columns make them very long when items are added to the list.  I have to use an Issue List because of the 'send email when item is Assigned To someone' feature.

My goal is to narrow the 'Created By' and 'Modified By' columns because the names are so long that they take up a ton of space without wrapping down to the second line making the other columns super narrow and making the list look terrible.  I use Designer and have tried multiple fixes I've found online that involve removing the 'nowrap=nowrap' code and adding length, overflow, and white-space code to the columns.  The steps I have taken can be found here: http://smallbusiness.chron.com/change-width-columns-sharepoint-47331.html, as well as other places online including some threads on this forum.

My problem is that making these changes does make the columns narrower on my site.... when it contains no items.  As soon as I add an item, the two columns stretch out with my super long Display Name taking up one line and therefore smushing all the other columns and making their text wrap down to like 10 lines in some cases.  Whats weird is that if I open up Designer after I add an item to the list- the site actually looks correct in Designer with my Display Name wrapped over 3 or 4 lines and the columns being as narrow as they're supposed to be- but this doesn't reflect on the actual site.

Is there anyway I can get these columns narrower and keep them that way or make my Display Names wrap so they dont take up so much space horizontally.  Am I missing something here?  Is this not possible because of the type of columns they are?  Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following style within the page using Content Editor webpart...

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-vh, .ms-vh2-nofilter, .ms-vh2-nograd, .ms-vh2, .ms-vb
{
    white-space: normal;
}
</style>
```

I got the information from [Ryan’s post](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2011/06/word-wrapping-sharepoint-list-column-headers/).